# The import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient

Tags: android

hi i want to use import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClien but ihave error cannot be resolved please say me how to solve that error

Comment: open your sdk manager and check the extra packages are installed correctly

Comment: yes google playe service instaleed

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: i cant find biuld.gradle

Comment: Are you developing in android studio?